# Update a Apikey for a method in Api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**Usecase**

How can i update the API keys in apigateway ? Means when deploying the `CFN Stack`  i had created a `API key` for a method(i.e.`adbickyda`) . After some time i need to change the `API key` to a new one(i.e.`asdfasfdj`) .

Is this possible ? I checked the method `apikey:update` but except for `apikey` they have update options for all(i.e.Name, description etc)

Thanks
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe your API key is tied to a `usage plan` which is linked to a `API stage`. e.g. this is what I have in my CFN script.

```
ApiUsagePlan:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
  Properties:
    ApiStages: 
    - ApiId: !Ref MsApi
      Stage: !Ref TestStage     
    Description: !Join [" ", [{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "usage plan"]]
    Quota:
      Limit: 2000
      Period: MONTH
    Throttle:
    BurstLimit: 10
    RateLimit: 10
    UsagePlanName: !Join ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-usage-plan"]]
ApiUsagePlanKey:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey"
  Properties:
    KeyId: !Ref ApiKey
    KeyType: API_KEY
    UsagePlanId: !Ref ApiUsagePlan
```

I think you will have to add another `API key` to the `usage plan` and then delete the old `API key`. I am not sure if all of this is possible through CFN scripts but you can certainly use [CFN custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) functionality to call a lambda function which does this. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I just changed the `apikey` name property in  `"AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey"` and deployed the stack which in turn changed the APIKEY.

Comment: Could you please post your answer, for reference. Thanks.